# How to Show Contact is Selected in ios

Tags: ios, colors, contacts, addressbook

I am working on an Address book and now i want to Show that the contact i have select in Addressbook it should appear in  blue color ...

```
AS LIKE IN IPHONE WE CAN SEE ...
```

For that i have done this much coding ...

```
 ABRecordRef person = NULL;
    NSString *name = nil;
    if(gPerson == NULL)
    {
        person = ABPersonCreate();
        name = strReceiversNames;
    }
    else
    {
        person = gPerson;
        NSString *fName = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(gPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSString *lName = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(gPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", fName, lName];
    }

    CFErrorRef  error = NULL;

    //UILabel *ContectInfo;
//  ContectInfo.text = strPhoneNumber;
//  ContectInfo.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    // set name
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, (CFStringRef)name, &error);

    // set phone number
    ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneNumber = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(phoneNumber, (CFStringRef)strPhoneNumber, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel,NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phoneNumber, &error);
    CFRelease(phoneNumber);

    if(error != NULL) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }

    ABPersonViewController *ctrl = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
```

In this strPhoneNumber is my Contact number .. 
I just want to show it as blue color while i click on button ....

strPhoneNumber is NSString ..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use like this .

use this while u pick your Contact .

```
ABPersonViewController *ctrl = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
[ctrl setHighlightedItemForProperty:kABPersonPhoneProperty withIdentifier:0];
```

and call this function at the end

```
- (void)setHighlightedItemForProperty:(ABPropertyID)property withIdentifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{

}
```

So now what ever number u have select from addressbook that shows in blue color ...

Answer (score 1):

Why not use ABPersonViewController's setHighlightedItemForProperty:withIdentifier: method? Or maybe change the displayedPerson property? Hope this gives you a good direction.